# How to turn off all touch input at application, window or control level?

Tags: wpf, touch, inkcanvas

Using c# for a wpf application, if in Windows 7 touch is enabled in the control panel, a user by default can 'write' on an `InkCanvas` with a finger. I want to disable that and force stylus input only.

I'd like to know how to do it more than one way if possible: first by disabling touch on the `InkCanvas`, second by disabling it for a particular window, and third by disabling it for the entire application. A bonus fourth would be knowing how to turn touch on or off system-wide.

I have tried `UnregisterTouchWindow`, and I have tried setting `Stylus.SetIsTouchFeedbackEnabled` to false for the `InkCanvas`, but neither has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further digging helped me put together the following as a way to toggle touch on/off system-wide. If anyone knows how to accomplish this in any of the other 3 ways, I'd still appreciate those answers.

The basic steps are to check the current registry status, change it if necessary (and then refresh the system to recognize the change), and make note of the initial state to restore if needed on program exit.

Thanks to the posters at these [two](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-491406.html) [links](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Change_IE7_Proxy_Setting.aspx) for the education.

```
public MainWindow(){

    InitializeComponent();

    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
    regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch", true);
    string currKey = regKey.GetValue("TouchGate").ToString();
    if (currKey == "1")
    {
        regKey.SetValue("TouchGate", 0x00000000);
        User32Utils.Notify_SettingChange();
        UserConfig.TGate = "1";
    }
    regKey.Close();
    ...
}


public static class UserConfig {
    public static string TGate { get; set; }
    ...
}


private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e){
    ...
    if (UserConfig.TGate == "1")
    {
        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch", true);
        regKey.SetValue("TouchGate", 0x00000001);
        User32Utils.Notify_SettingChange();
        regKey.Close();
    }
}



//------------------User32Utils.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace (...)
{
    internal class User32Utils
    {
        #region USER32 Options
        static IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffffL);
        static IntPtr WM_SETTINGCHANGE = new IntPtr(0x1a);
        #endregion

        #region STRUCT
        enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
        {
            SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0000,
            SMTO_BLOCK = 0x0001,
            SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
            SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x0008
        }
        #endregion

        #region Interop

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd,
                                                uint Msg,
                                                UIntPtr wParam,
                                                UIntPtr lParam,
                                                SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags,
                                                uint uTimeout,
                                                out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
        #endregion

        internal static void Notify_SettingChange()
        {
            UIntPtr result;
            SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, (uint)WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
                               UIntPtr.Zero, UIntPtr.Zero,
                                SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, out result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Notify_SettingChange function can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/335a5bc9-9a9b-4fc5-b1c6-80aedf527abf

Comment: What if your application crashes before the Closing event?

Comment: @matscol In Windows 8.1 this key has been moved to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder.  So you would have to change above solution `RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser` to `RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine`.  This line is in two locations: `MainWindow_Closing()` and `MainWindow()` constructor.

Comment: I'm finding that Windows 8 is not recognizing this registry change on the fly when I change the key in the Local_Machine folder.  The commenter on the answer post here had the same issue on Win8. [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684560/update-registry-changes-of-wisp-windows-ink-service-platform-with-c-sharp)