# Update registry changes of WISP (Windows Ink Service Platform) with C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry, touch

I am trying to enable/disable touch capability on Windows 7 or 8 for my WPF drawing application.

As far as I searched, the link [How to turn off all touch input at application, window or control level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120890/how-to-turn-off-all-touch-input-at-application-window-or-control-level) gives a right location of the registry for touch capability status.

However, it did not be affected on-the-fly because windows system may not be acknowledged the changes.

In my assumption, User32.dll refresh with **SystemParametersInfo** is required to make changes without reboot.
But hard to figure out how to do that because I don't know which [SPI_*something*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Input) is related to WISP.

Is there another method or could you help me to make it happen?

The sample code is as below (pretty similar to above StackOverflow referenced link)

```
            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch", true);
        if (regKey != null)
        {
            regKey.SetValue("TouchGate", 0x00000000); // Turn off touch.
            regKey.Close();

            // NOTIFY REGISTRY CHANGES TO WINDOWS
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current answer to the question *How to turn off all touch input at application, window or control level?* also gives a way to make Windows to re-read registry. See: [the answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128991/391693)
`internal static void Notify_SettingChange()` method.

There is no documented SPI_* constant for touch disabling in **SystemParametersInfo**. Moreover all the SPI_ constants there are related to accessibility features - not general features like touch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realize the Notify_SettingChange is given from interop. Strangely, it doesn't works for me(Win8), but it works when I manually edit the registry value.