# How to disable touch screen in windows 8?

Tags: winapi, windows-8

I want to disable Touch screen in window 8, but i have some trouble when changed the registry.

After i change registry i must restart the computer. If not restart the computer i can't disable touch screen.But i hope to disable touch screen without restart computer. 
Here is my code:

```
int EnableTouchScreen(bool enable)
{
    EnableMulTouch(enable);
    EnableTouch(enable);

    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, NULL, NULL, SMTO_NORMAL,1,&dwRet);

    return 0;
}  

int EnableMulTouch(bool enable) 
{
    HKEY hkey;
    LONG lResult;
    DWORD dwtype; 

    if(IsWin64())
    {
        lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Wisp\\MultiTouch\\"), 0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_ALL_ACCESS |KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
    }
    else
    {
    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Wisp\\MultiTouch\\"), 0, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_ALL_ACCESS |KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
    }

    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        DWORD value = 0;

        if(enable)
        {
             value = 1;
             lResult = RegSetValueEx(hkey, _T("MultiTouchEnabled"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD));
        }
        else
        {
            value = 0;
            lResult = RegSetValueEx(hkey, _T("MultiTouchEnabled"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD));
        }

        if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
        {
            char strErr[256];
            sprintf(strErr, "SetMulTouch --- GetLastError(): %u\n", GetLastError() );
            OutputDebugStringA(strErr);

            return FALSE;
        }

        RegCloseKey(hkey);
   }

   return 0;
}

int EnableTouch(bool enable)
{
    HKEY hkey;
    LONG lResult; 
    DWORD dwtype; 

    if(IsWin64())
{
    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Wisp\\Touch\\"), 0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_ALL_ACCESS |KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
}
else
{

    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Wisp\\Touch\\"), 0, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_ALL_ACCESS |KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
}

if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{
    DWORD value = 0;

    if(enable)
    {
        value = 1;
        lResult = RegSetValueEx(hkey, _T("TouchGate"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD));
        value = 0;
        lResult = RegSetValueEx(hkey, _T("PanningDisabled"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD));
    }
    else
    {
        value = 0;
        lResult = RegSetValueEx(hkey, _T("TouchGate"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD));
        value = 1;
        lResult = RegSetValueEx(hkey, _T("PanningDisabled"), 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD));
    }

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        char strErr[256];
        sprintf(strErr, "SetMulTouch --- GetLastError(): %u\n"GetLastError() ); 
        OutputDebugStringA(strErr);
        return FALSE;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hkey);
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you going through so much effort to do this? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to disable the screen touh immediately without reboot the computer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this helps program wise, but you can disable / enable the touch screen by short cut in windows 8 using this app.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html

Download it in your language and you'll have to use console commands after creating a shortcut

1. Open regular device manager
2. Locate your touchscreen driver **
3. Launch device manager you downloaded
4. Locate the touchscreen driver you want to disable
5. Properties menu on it
6. Copy [Device Instance ID] to notepad
7. Create a shortcut to the device manager you downloaded
8. Add the following to the end of the target name ***

   - /enable "[Device Instance ID]"+
   - /disable "[Device Instance ID]"+

Of course you'll want both so make two shortcuts.

** (it'll be one of the Human Interface Drivers, disable one at a time until you find out which is touch screen if you're unsure, be careful not to disable more than one at a time or risk being locked out of your computer!!)

***don't add the +'s, just whats between them

Comment: Thank you so much, now i using "devcon.exe" tools to disable all HID,But i don't know whether it will Lead to other problems

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to matscol, he answered his own similar question here:

[How to turn off all touch input at application, window or control level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120890/how-to-turn-off-all-touch-input-at-application-window-or-control-level)

It would still be nice to only disable it at the application level and not system-wide, like the registry hack does.

I will use this solution for now, but I will be looking for something better.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8.1

1. I right clicked on "Four Square" icon (used to be Start Button)
2. Device Manager
3. N-trig DuoSense(R) Digitizers
4. Right click "N-trig Duosense Touch HID Interface"
5. Disable

DONE!