# Unable to set registry value from WinRT Brokered Component

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

We are using an x86 brokered component in order to allow a sideloaded Windows Store App (also compiled as x86) to perform interactions that store apps cannot usually perform. One of the things we're trying to do is modify the value of the `TouchGate` registry key in order to temporarily disable touch input (using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120890/how-to-turn-off-all-touch-input-at-application-window-or-control-level/5128991#5128991)).

I have observed the 64-bit and 32-bit registries using regedit, as well as the WOW64 hive on the 64-bit registry. My code reports a successful modification to the registry value each time (no exceptions or error messages), but none of the values in the registry ever actually change. The corresponding message dispatch to update all windows also doesn't seem to have any impact. Is there anything about these brokered components that should cause these particular APIs to not have any effect?